# Sorting array of integers C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

i'm a beginner c programmer studying computer science and i'm trying to create a sorting program to sort an array of integers although i keep getting wrong results, this is what i got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    
#define TAM 9

int sort_array(int num1[],int num2[]);    
int main(){
    int i=0;   
    int num1[TAM] = {5,6,2,4,7,1,3,0};
    int num2[TAM] = {0};
    int * ptr_num2 = num2;

    sort_array(num1,num2);

    while(*ptr_num2 != '\0'){
        printf("%c",*ptr_num2+48);
        ptr_num2++;
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}

int sort_array(int num1[],int num2[]){
    int min=256,max=0,i,j;
    int * ptr_num1 = num1;
    int * ptr_max = num1;
    int * ptr_num2 = num2;

    /* check for max */
    while(*ptr_max != '\0'){
        if(*ptr_max > max) max = *ptr_max;
        ptr_max++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<TAM-1;i++){
        /* check for min */
        for(j=0;j<TAM-1;j++){
            if(*ptr_num1 < min) min = *ptr_num1;
            ptr_num1++;
            num1[i] = max;
        }
        *ptr_num2 = min;
        ptr_num2++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've been banging my head for several hours on this already.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that some of these things might not make sense since i'm just experimenting with a few things.

Comment: For some specific input, what is your actual and your expected output?

Comment: Also you have possible [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your program, as the array `num1` is declared to contain nine elements, but you only initialize *eight*, which means the value of the last element is indeterminate.

Comment: Why would you opt for such a complicated sorting routine ? Are there any strange requirements ?

Comment: Also, why the null-at-the-end trick? Can't you use the actual length ?

Comment: @Joachim, im trying to sort the array num1 from smaller numbers to bigger numbers if you know what i mean, and also, i gave the array 8 numbers, the rest is initialised to 0 if not specified right?

Comment: @oglu i had a worse one before, i just can't think of anything simpler than this atm

Comment: Are there any special requirements ? You could use a simple array int[] and sort it in place with a trivial sorting algorithm (bubble sort). Example : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation

Comment: I'm trying to do it with mostly pointers since it's what im the weakest at, the whole sorting thing im using is looking for the smallest integer in the main array and copying it to another array while at the same time i'm 'deleting' (equaling to the max number) the same smallest number in the original array

Comment: Sorry, but recommend deleting `sort_array(int num1[],int num2[])` and re-write with a new approach - too many logic errors in it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you do not know about the typical array sorts... Well, let me to introduce you to one of the more simple ones. Allthough it's usually not the most efficient one, it's the easiest one to understand, and considering the fact you are messing with little arrays and not databases, it will be just fine.

I am talking about good old Chum, our **Bubble sort**.

Bubble sort is a well known simple array sorting algorithm -
The logic is simple. You go over the whole array on pairs of two - I.e, Array[0] with Array[1], Array[1] with Array[2], etc...

Whenever you find that things are not the way they are supposed to be - in your case, The larger index number is bigger than the lower index number - you swap between them, until you reach an iteration where you passed through the whole array and didnt swap at all.

In case you didn't understand well, here's Pseudo code from wikipedia (OMG who the heck uses wikipedia i'm such a n00b):

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
n = length(A)
repeat 
 swapped = false
 for i = 1 to n-1 inclusive do
   /* if this pair is out of order */
   if A[i-1] > A[i] then
     /* swap them and remember something changed */
     swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
     swapped = true
   end if
  end for
 until not swapped
end procedure
```

And here's some C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int array[100], n, c, d, swap; 
printf("Enter number of elements\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Enter %d integers\n", n);
for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
scanf("%d", &array[c]);
for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
{
for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
{
  if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
  {
    swap       = array[d];
    array[d]   = array[d+1];
    array[d+1] = swap;
    }
  }
}

printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

for ( c = 0 ; c < n ; c++ )
 printf("%d\n", array[c]);

return 0;
}
```

Here again, btw, the credit is not for me:
http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort

Hope this helped you, and good luck :)

Comment: @AAbranov, I've been programming for nearly 40 years and I consider wiki and other online resources to be a real time saver.  And I do not need to keep a bunch of reference manuals on my desk.